# how to use multiple tab bar controller in an application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have several buttons in root view and I want to switch different tab bar controller when click each button. How can I do this?

I did for just first 'Denetim Formu' button. When click it it show second picture. But How can I do like this for other 'Lokasyon, Taahhüdname, Form Sorgulama, ect' buttons. Each have to show different tab bar controller.

[image][image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, that sounds like an odd experience - can you come up with a different design that's not so jarring?

Comment: I edited my question above, can you look now??

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is on your particular button click:-
1.)Which tab bar button item and its view controller you want to change(identify it).

```
*YourViewController* *import=[[[*YourViewController* alloc]initWithNibName:@"*YourViewControllerNibName*" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *baseNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:import]autorelease];
    NSArray *arr=[[appDelegate tabBarController]viewControllers];
    NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:baseNav];
    [[appDelegate tabBarController]setViewControllers:array];
    appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1;

    UITabBarItem *item= [[[[appDelegate tabBarController]tabBar]items ]objectAtIndex:1];
    item.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hometab.png"];
    item.title=@"Home";
```

By this way you can change your tab bar view controller tab with its item name and image.

Comment: I dont wantto change selectedIndex of tabbar. I want to show another different tab bar controller.